# Angular 2, Using Jquery to Manipulate Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-directives

I'm pretty new with NG2, and I'm trying to add Slide Up/Down effects do default Bootstrap 4 Dropdown component.

The Bootstrap dropdown component has 2 Jquery Listeners `$(el).on('show.bs.dropdown')` and `$(el).on('hide.bs.dropdown')`. So I created a directive to add this effects:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropDownAnimate]'
})
export class DropDownAnimateDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
  @Input()
  appDropDownAnimate: boolean;

  private el = this.ElementRef.nativeElement;
  constructor(private ElementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked () {
    const el = this.el;
      debugger;
      $(el).on('show.bs.dropdown',
      (cb) => {
        $(el).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
      });
     $(el).on('hide.bs.dropdown',
     (cb) => {
        $(el).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
     });
  }
}
```

Although no errors is trigged, it has no effect :/. BUT!!! At the debugger point, while the browser is frozen, if I copy/paste the code at the console, It DOES work. So I'm really frustrated because I'm pretty sure my code is right, but I can't see why it won't work inside the code definition.

PS: I've tried to wrap it on setTimeout to see if it was a DOM rendering issue, and also didn't work. I've also tried all NG2 Lifehooks.

If anyone could help me solve this issue and also explain to me the why of this odd behaviour, I would be very grateful.

SPECS:

Bootstrap 4, Angular 4.3, JQuery 3.2.1

Comment: You said everything besides the current error that you are having! Could you post the console exception? Also you should use AfterViewInit instead of AfterViewChecked!

Comment: There is no error, the slide just don't work :/. But if i copy/paste 
`$(el).on('show.bs.dropdown',
      (cb) => {
        $(el).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
      });
     $(el).on('hide.bs.dropdown',
     (cb) => {
        $(el).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
     });
`

during the debugging point, when the browser is frozen. It starts to work

Comment: AfterViewInit will garant the view fully loaded, then you should be able to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I've also tried AfterViewInit, and all the others XD. Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God!

I was suppose to `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and the app.module.ts not in the directive.

Even there, still weird, Importing jquery at the module.ts or my directive.ts shouldn't be an issue I believe. I was suppose to be able the user $ method at that point anyway.